# Não consigo retornar o valor solicitado ( MongoDB )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

estou tentando fazer uma lista de nomes de pessoas que estão cadastradas no meu banco de dados mongo, e printar na web

O model que eu estou usando é esse

```js
const mongoose = require('../../database/conn')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

function adicionaZero(numero){
    if (numero <= 9) 
        return "0" + numero
    else
        return numero
}

var dataAtual = new Date()
var dataAtualFormatada = (adicionaZero(dataAtual.getDate().toString()) + "/" + (adicionaZero(dataAtual.getMonth()+1).toString()) + "/" + dataAtual.getFullYear())

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    senha: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: false
    },
    senhaResetToken: {
        type: String,
        select: false
    },
    senhaResetExpires: {
        type: Date,
        select: false
    },
    data_registro: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: dataAtualFormatada
    }
})

UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.senha, 10)
    this.senha = hash

    next()
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Router

```js
router.get('/comunidade', async (req, res) => {
const cookieCheck = req.cookies['PdSO']
const perfil = await User.findOne({ "_id": cookieCheck['id'] })

User.find().then((membros) => {
            if(!cookieCheck)
                return res.send("VC N ESTA LOGADO")

                return res.render("pages/index/comunidade", {
                "membros": membros,
                "nomes": nome,
                "css_file": "/comunidade.css"
                
        }).catch ( (err) => {
            console.log("ERR: " + err)
        })
    })
})
```

Handlebars

```html
                <div class="container-comunidade">
                    <h4>Comunidade</h4>
                    <div class="container-comunidade-wraper">
                        {{> membros }}
                    </div><!--/container-comunidade-wraper-->
                </div><!--/container-comunidade-->
```

Membros.handlebars

```html
{{#each membros}}

                        <div class="container-comunidade-single">
                            <div class="img-comunidade-user-single">
                                <img src="/img/test/avatar.jpg" />
                            </div><!--/img-comunidade-user-single-->
                            <div class="info-comunidade-user-single">
                                <h2> {{ nomes }} </h2>
                                <br />
                            <div class="btn-solicitar-amizade">
                                <a href="#">Solicitar Amizade</a>
                            </div><!--btn-solicitar-amizade-->
                            </div><!--info-comunidade-user-single-->
                        </div><!--/container-comunidad-single-->
{{else}}

                        <div class="container-comunidade-single">
                            <div class="img-comunidade-user-single">
                                <img src="/img/test/avatar.jpg" />
                            </div><!--/img-comunidade-user-single-->
                            <div class="info-comunidade-user-single">
                                <h2> 0 </h2>
                                <br />
                            <div class="btn-solicitar-amizade">
                                <a href="#">Solicitar Amizade</a>
                            </div><!--btn-solicitar-amizade-->
                            </div><!--info-comunidade-user-single-->
                        </div><!--/container-comunidad-single-->
{{/each}}
```

**PS: Mostra os perfis dos membros cadastrados, mas não exibe nomes de nenhum deles**

Agradeço desde já ah todos, e desculpe pelo tamanho da quest é que eu sou um animal e to aprendendo ainda.

Comment: Hey olá!
Já experimentaste

```db.collection.find({}, { nome: 1, _id: 0 });```
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa voltei aqui, encontrei um jeito para deixar a listagem do jeito que eu quero, so falto adicionar a "query" **lean** depois do find e não precisa colocar o valor do nome na rota que ele ja aparece automaticamente.

```js
router.get('/comunidade', async (req, res) => {
const cookieCheck = req.cookies['PdSO']
const perfil = await User.findOne({ "_id": cookieCheck['id'] })

User.find().lean().then((membros) => {
            if(!cookieCheck)
                return res.send("VC N ESTA LOGADO")

                return res.render("pages/index/comunidade", {
                "membros": membros,
                "css_file": "/comunidade.css"
             })
                
        }).catch ( (err) => {
            console.log("ERR: " + err)
        })
})
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score -2):

Opa beleza? vou dar uma mexida legal no seu código, só pra deixar ele um pouco mais organizado, e voce tenta ai, iremos alterar o router (acho que o jeito que voce esta chamando o obj esta incorreto).

```
     async function index(membros) {
     try {
      if(!cookieCheck) {
       return "voce nao esta logado";
       }
           this.user = async User.find();
           const nomeUsers = this.user.data[1].nome;

         return res.render("pages/index/comunidade", {
                "nomes": this.nomeUsers,
                "css_file": "/comunidade.css"

    } 
} 
   catch(e) {
    
     console.log(e);
       
     }
   }
```

espero que funcione

Comment: esqueci de colocar o this na const nomeUsers, muda ela pra this.nomeUsers = this.user.data[1].nome;

Comment: Você pode editar a resposta para adicionar as informações faltantes

Comment: Opa eae, eu testei aqui não funcionou, pagina não carregou nem apareceu nenhum erro no console